# Checking MySQL Logs for Possibility of Performance Issues/DOS attack

Tags: php, mysql

We write a most of our websites in PHP and use MySQL database connections routinely. We are currently encountering a major performance issue on our dedicated server. When accessing our server it loads webpages very slowly and SSH'ing into the machine takes forever. We have restarted it a few times and after a few minutes that problem appears again.

Our web host (MidPhase) says that it could be related to a DOS attack and that they are going to place our dedicated server on CiscoGuard for 24hrs and check our server logs to verify if that is the case.

I'm concerned that we may have some poorly coded PHP scripts that are being exploited.

How would one check server wide for problems that could be caused by possibly PHP/MySQL injection exploits?

Thank you,
Tegan

Comment: Looks like I may have found the culprit. I used "ps aux" and saw that mysql was using like 24% of our CPU.

Then I looked at the mysql running processes and noticed that one of our clients was getting hammered.

This was a client using an older version of Drupal and somebody was trying to brute force the login. I disabled the site entirely and things appear to be running better now.

Classic case of someone not staying up to date on security patches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check access logs for unusual requests (specially those indicating SQL injection, or massive requests to the same urls), and also enabling MySQL's slow query log can be useful, since it will allow you to see any heavy query that can indicate either someone dumping your db, or your own code performing poorly on queries.

Consider modifying the slow query time value (default 10 seconds) to have a valuable log, and not empty / bloated with queries.

Using mtop to go over MySQL's performance in real-time may be helpfull too.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use a LAMP setup, I would start with something like

```
$ top
```

or

```
$ ps aux
```

to see what process is using lots of resources. It could be php / mysql but it could also be a mail server or a spam filter (just an example, if you are running that on the same server).

Comment: Yes it is a LAMP setup. 

Let say after I run the above commands I see that mysql is using lots of resources.

How could I dig down deeper and check out what individual PHP page could be causing an issue.

Comment: That´s a tricky one, I remember looking for that and not finding it. Apart from checking which pages get loaded more than normal in the httpd logs, I can only recommend asking the same question on serverfault.com. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest simply going through any PHP, and making sure that queries are being escaped (or use binding), and also that you're filtering for possible XSS attacks.